# What is the convention behind the orientation of data in pyplot's contour?

Tags: matplotlib

There are two different ways to call pyplot's `contour` plot function, as illustrated here:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])  # x has length M=5.
    y = np.array([10, 20, 30])  # y has length N=3

    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

    """
    x_grid = array(
    [[0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4]])

    x_grid varies along index 0 (the rows). Similarly, y_grid varies along index 1
    (the columns). x_grid and y_grid have shape (M, N) = (5, 3).
    """

    z_grid = x_grid + y_grid
    """
    z_grid = array(
    [[10, 20, 30],
     [11, 21, 31],
     [12, 22, 32],
     [13, 23, 33],
     [14, 24, 34]])

    z_grid varies by 1 along the rows and 10 along the columns.
    """

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    # First call signature of contour
    contour = axes[0].contour(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid, levels=20)
    axes[0].clabel(contour, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
    axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
    axes[0].grid()
    axes[0].set_title("First call signature")

    # Second call signature of contour
    contour = axes[1].contour(y, x, z_grid, levels=20)
    axes[1].clabel(contour, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    axes[1].set_xlabel('y')
    axes[1].set_ylabel('x')
    axes[1].grid()
    axes[1].set_title("Second call signature")

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

In the first case, I pass the 2D arrays returned by `meshgrid` for `X` and `Y`, whereas in the second case I pass the 1D arrays that I passed into `meshgrid` for `X` and `Y`. However, I had to swap their order, because the plots are transposed *despite* the fact that I've passed the same dependent data `z_grid` into `contour()` in both cases.

Why does `contour` work this way?

Answer (score 0):

It is about the indexing used by `meshgrid`. The default (see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)) is Cartesian indexing ("xy"), which is the one used by Matplotlib (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html)).

Say, you want to created a contour:

```
contour(X, Y, Z)
```

**Option 1**

One option is to provide X, Y and Z all with the same 2D size. This is what you do in the first case. X and Y were created by:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
#x_grid, y_grid
```

and Z created afterwards with the same 2D size as X and Y. In this case, contour does not need to assume anything, as you are already providing the three arguments in the same form of 2D grid.

**Option 2**

On the other hand, you can provide 1D arrays. However, in this case, Contour needs to run meshgrid by itself. Something like

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')
```

Contour uses "xy" indexing. This means that these X and Y are now different from the ones above, because of the distinct indexing used on each case.

Accordingly, in this second option, Contour assumes that the Z was created under "xy" indexing.

So:

```
x -> size (N)
y -> size (M)
X -> size (M, N) 
Y -> size (M, N)
```

but...

```
Z -> size (N,M)
```

Because you created Z by "ij", but Contour created X and Y by "xy". Hence the mismatch.

When you plot instead `contour(y, x, z_grid)`, now X and Y will now have the same shape as Z, so the Contour does not throw any error, because all arrays are in the form (N, M).

Comment: I understand the difference between `xy` and `ij` indexing in `meshgrid`. I do not understand why `contour` plots the *same* `z_grid` data differently in the cases where I use 1D or 2D arrays for `X` and `Y` in the call to `contour`. From this answer, I still do not understand what's going on. Can you clarify that point?